# The friend who travels with you

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases

I am trying find a phrase or just a word that expresses the friend who travels with you along your trip or journey.

> You are my best ***_*___** .

How can I call this person?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

*Companion* means exactly this, without any addition.  The word has expanded over time, but the original sense (and meaning 1a in the OED) is

> One who associates with or accompanies another; a mate; a fellow.

Comment: The Doctor has his companions, and that is good enough a word for me.

Comment: @Dino Beytar - If you were to use this word, you should probably consider changing your example sentence to `You are my boon companion`.

Comment: @TED - `boon companion` means `close friend`?

Comment: The very fact that it has "expanded over time" suggests to me that it is (now) often worth the additional clarifying word; thus I prefer Urbycoz's answer.  (Though your answer is of course not wrong and won't get any downvote from me.)

Comment: 'companion' is technically correct, but not something anyone would actually say, mainly because the word 'best' is not appropriate here.

Answer (score 7):

You could use any of the following:

> travelling companion / travelmate / travel partner

Myself, I would probably favour "travelling companion".

*Edit: As several people have pointed out, the word "**[companion](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/companion)**" alone would be sufficient.*

Comment: What about `Travel Chumb`. I just found it...

Comment: Surely, you mean `travel chum` ? No, `travelling companion` is perfectly fine.

Comment: yes, sorry for spelling. I found `travelling companion` too long -because I thought English makes everything shorter :) For instance, in my language I have to call every word `I hope it is not` But some of you say just `Hope not!`

Comment: @dino: You can shorten it to just "companion" if you want.

Comment: "Companion" is standard.

Comment: I kind of think "companion" alone has been co-opted as a SO/partner/girlfriend synonym, and would stick with "traveling companion".

Comment: First, let me say I completely agree with @smackfu.  Adding one word is a reasonable cost to reduce the chance of misinterpretation.  Secondly, I would like to point out that, at least in American English, the preferred spelling is *traveling*.

Answer (score 1):

How about `travelling buddy`?

Definition of `Buddy` is, a friend or partner for a particular activity, and it is often used in that sense. E.g, "climbing buddy", "diving buddy", etc.

`You are my best companion` is technically correct, but not something someone would ever say, because 'best' implies a comparison that is not appropriate to the term 'companion', given the modern broadening of the meaning of the word. Buddy still has a limited range of interpretation though, and so `You are my best travelling buddy` is something that one might actually hear.

Answer (score 1):

***comrade*** would suit as an alternative if you must use a single word especially as it owes its origins to the same French source as the word *camaraderie*

Answer (score -2):

You can call the person your **peripatetic**.
https://www.google.com/search?q=name+someone+that+accompanies+you+on+trips+-+how+to+answer&oq=n&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i57j69i59j0l5.12986j0j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: This would benefit from some explanation of _why_ you believe this is a suitable word (including a dictionary link).

Comment: **...especially** since *peripatetic* is usually an adjective and the word doesn't appear at all in the Google results you link to (for me, in the UK).

Comment: Google searches aren't the same for everyone. Mine just shows a link to this question as a top hit.